# Import issues with custom ModelField that refers to a Model in the same app

Tags: python

I've created a series of custom ModelFields that are simply restricted ForeignKeys. Below you'll find CompanyField. When instantiated, you may provide a type (e.g., Client, Vendor). With a type provided, the field ensures that only values that have the appropriate type are allowed.

The crm app, the one that defines the custom fields, compiles and runs just fine. Eventually I added references to the fields to a different app (incidents) using "from crm import fields". Now I'm seeing a whole bunch of errors like this:

> incidents.incident: 'group' has a relation with model Company, which has either not been installed or is abstract.

Here are all the gory details. Please let me know if there's any more information I could provide which may be helpful.

```
## crm/fields.py

import models as crmmods

class CompanyField(models.ForeignKey):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # This is a hack to get South working. In either case, we just need to
        # make sure the FK refers to Company.
        try:
            # kwargs['to'] == crmmods.company doesn't work for some reason I
            # still haven't figured out
            if str(kwargs['to']) != str(crmmods.Company):
                raise AttributeError("Only crm.models.Company is accepted " + \
                    "for keyword argument 'to'")
        except:
            kwargs['to'] = 'Company'

        # See if a CompanyType was provided and, if so, store it as self.type
        if len(args) > 0:
            company_type = args[0]
            # Type is expected to be a string or CompanyType
            if isinstance(company_type, str):
                company_type = company_type.upper()
                if hasattr(crmmods.CompanyType, company_type):
                    company_type = getattr(crmmods.CompanyType, company_type)
                else:
                    raise AttributeError(
                        "%s is not a valid CompanyType." % company_type)
            elif not isinstance(company_type, crmmods.CompanyType):
                raise AttributeError(
                    "Expected str or CompanyType for first argument.")

            self.type = company_type
        else:
            self.type = None

        super(CompanyField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        # Restrict the formfield so it only displays Companies with the correct
        # type.
        if self.type:
            kwargs['queryset'] = \
                crmmods.Company.objects.filter(companytype__role=self.type)
        return super(CompanyField, self).formfield(**kwargs)

    def validate(self, value, model_instance):
        super(CompanyField, self).validate(value, model_instance)

        # No type set, nothing to check.
        if not value or not self.type:
            return

        # Ensure that value is correct type.
        if not \
        value.companytype_set.filter(role=self.type).exists():
            raise ValidationError("Company does not have the " + \
                "required roles.")

## crm/models.py

import fields

class CompanyType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class Company(models.Model):
    type = models.ForeignKey(CompanyType)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    company = fields.CompanyField("Client")

## incidents/models.py

from crm import fields as crmfields

class Incident(models.Model):
    company = crmfields.CompanyField("Client")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The was fixed, after much toil, simply by changing

```
kwargs['to'] = 'Company'
```

to

```
kwargs['to'] = 'crm.Company'
```

It seems that when the 'to' argument was evaluated outside of the crm app, it was evaluating it in the context of the incidents app. That is, it was looking for 'incidents.Company' which, as the error message suggested, didn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular package dependency. `fields` imports `models` which imports `fields` which imports `models` which imports `fields` . . .

Circular package dependecies are A BAD IDEA(tm). Although it *may* work in some cases, it doesn't work in your case, for a complicated reason involving metaclasses, which I will spare myself.

**EDIT**

The reason is that the Django ORM module uses metaclasses to turn its class variables (the fields of the Model) into property descriptors on the object. This is done at class definition time by the metaclass. A class is defined when the module is loaded. For this reason its attributes must also be defined at class loading. This is unlike the code of a method, where references to names are resolved the moment a class is executed.

Now, since you refer to a `field` object in your class definition from `models` and back again, this will not work.

If you place all three in the same package, your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I understand that circular dependencies are a bad idea. I think this is a rare case where it's necessary as I don't think these files all belong in the same package. Could you link me to some information on the issues involving metaclasses?

Comment: Josh, I have updated my answer to explain about the metaclasses. I am not trying to be "poltically correct" about circular dependecies, I am afraid it will simply not work in your case.

Comment: It's kind of like having the choice between a beautiful and clean design that will not work and an ugly and messy design that does the job. Life's full of hard choices ;-)

Although in this case, I don't think it is ugly or messy to merge these three packages into one.

Comment: Josh, any news on this one? I am curious if you managed to solve this.

Comment: Hey Hans, thanks for checking in. Turns out that the issue was pretty small really. See my answer. I voted your answer up because the information is still solid.